# delphi- what does rewrite file actually do?

Tags: delphi

Does `Rewrite` clear file contents of existing file or does it delete it and create a new one?
I have a text file in my *app.exe* folder which I need to clear. Any example?

Comment: Assign/Rewrite/Reset are the classic Pascal file I/O functions. They are deprecated, at least mentally, by all modern Delphi developers. Also they have some weird quirks on Windows 7 and later.  I have gotten rid of all mine as fast as possible, and replaced it with modern Stream based IO.

Comment: Warren, I'd be curious to know about these quirks that affect the classic I/O functions under Windows 7. I'm maintaining systems that include code written in 1984 which hasn't been fixed as it has not been broken.  Did it break without me noticing?

Comment: These quirks affect me but I have not seen a general consensus from the rest of the community. Basically I get permission-denied exceptions (with {$I+} on) or silent I/O write failures, on Windows Vista and Windows 7, when I use classic Pascal IO `Assign/Reset/Rewrite` procedures.  I believe it has something to do with default file folder permissions and NTFS, and some global variables that Assign/Reset/Rewrite use to decide how much permissions to grab when doing I/O on a file. The use of such globals is manageable in some contexts, and not in others.

Comment: So, for example, one might have a legacy application that uses Reset to read from a file, which, by default, requests read/write access.  When run under Vista, that file might now be read-only. The developer can fix this by setting FileMode appropriately. Is this the kind of thing that you're speaking of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Delphi XE2 documentation, topic [Rewrite](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rewrite) - read the last quoted paragraph:

> Creates a new file and opens it.
>
> In Delphi code, Rewrite creates a new external file with the name assigned to F.
>
> F is a variable of any file type associated with an external file using AssignFile. RecSize is an optional expression that can be specified only if F is an untyped file. If F is an untyped file, RecSize specifies the record size to be used in data transfers. If RecSize is omitted, a default record size of 128 bytes is assumed.
>
> If an external file with the same name already exists, it is deleted and a new empty file is created in its place.

From the same documentation, link at the bottom of page for `System.Rewrite`, modified to use your app's folder:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  F: TextFile;
  AppDir: string;
begin
  // Instead of ParamStr(0), you can use Application.ExeName
  // if you prefer
  AppDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)); 
  AssignFile(F, AppDir + 'NEWFILE.$$$');
  Rewrite(F);  // default record size is 128 bytes
  Writeln(F, 'Just created file with this text in it...');
  CloseFile(F);
  MessageDlg('NEWFILE.$$$ has been created in the ' + AppDir + ' directory.',
    mtInformation, [mbOk], 0, mbOK);
end;
```

You should know, though, that `Rewrite` is outdated and doesn't support Unicode. You should be using more modern methods to read and write files like [TFileStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TFileStream) or [TStringWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStringWriter) (or even the simple solution of [TStringList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStringList)).

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  AppDir: string;
begin
  AppDir := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Add('Just created file with this text in it...');
    // Add more lines here if needed, and then only save once
    SL.SaveToFile(AppDir + 'NEWFILE.$$$');
    MessageDlg('NEWFILE.$$$ has been created in the ' + AppDir + ' directory.',
      mtInformation, [mbOk], 0, mbOK);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note that you cannot use `TStrings`; it's an abstract class. You need to use one of it's descendants instead (`TStringList` is the one used most often).

Comment: Your code above can also be rewritten as: `ioutils.TFile.WriteAllText('NEWFILE.$$$','just created a file with this text in it');`

Comment: @Wouter, that wasn't the question asked. There are probably 100 different ways to write the above code. The question specifically asked for an example of `Rewrite`. Thanks, though. :-)

Comment: +1 and `TStringList` I would say is the easiest possible way to read/write plain text files, perfect alternative for those who aren't comfortable using `AssignFile()` etc.

Comment: how would you do it with tstrings ? Writeln(F, ''); would do then ?

Comment: @user763539, see my last edit. And no, `WriteLn` doesn't work with `TStrings` descendants. If you have more questions about different ways to do it, please start a new question. :-)

Comment: @Ken: I didn't post an "answer to the question", but as a "comment to your post". :) Anyway, you mention several ways to write text to a file, but one seemed to be missing. I personally use `TFile.ReadAllText()` and `TFile.WriteAllText()` and `TFile.AppendAllText()` all the time. It's nice because you don't need to declare or free any variables.

Comment: @Wouter, the question also was tagged Delphi 7, which doesn't have `IOUtils`. I didn't try to list every possible way to write to a file; I suggested alternatives to `AssignFile/Rewrite` because they're so outdated, but I also tried to stay generic to cover D7/XE/XE2. No problem, though. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I did an experiment and determined that REWRITE overwrites an existing file. 
It does not delete and then recreate the file.
You'll have to learn a little about file tunneling, something I knew nothing about when I began.

```
program RewriteTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

//========================================================================
// Will REWRITE delete an existing file and create a new file,
// or will it overwrite the existing file?
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// According to the Delphi documentation, it will delete the old file and
// create a new one.  But is this true?
// Internally, it calls the Windows API CreateFile function with the
// CREATE_ALWAYS option.
// The Microsoft documentation for CreateFile says this will overwrite the
// existing file.
// Let's perform an experiment to see what really happens.
// Here are the steps in the experiment:
//
//    1. Select a file name.
//    2. Delete that file if it exists.
//    3. Create a file with that name.
//    4. Determine the creation time of that file. Call it A.
//
//   - - As with any experiment, we first need a control case.
//       We will explicitly delete the file we just created
//       and then recreate the file.
//
//    5. Wait a few seconds.
//    6. Delete the file that was just created.
//    7. Again, create a file with that same name.
//    8. Determine the creation time of this new file. Call it B.
//
//   - - We would expect that since the first file was deleted,
//       and a new file was created, that the creation times of
//       these files would be different.
//       I was quite surprised to find that this hypothesis
//       is WRONG!
//       This is why scientific experiments have controls!
//
//       Two separate files created at distinct times had the same
//       Creation Date according to the operating system.
//
//   - - TUNNELING:  It turns out our experimental results were gummed up
//       by something I knew nothing about before, called file tunneling.
//       The Windows operating system has this feature which will save the
//       existing meta-information about a file for "a short time" after it
//       is deleted or renamed.
//       If another file is created with the same name, or renamed
//       to that name, the new file will be assigned the same meta-data
//       as the original.
//       I won't go too far into this topic here. If you're interested you
//       can research it yourself. I'll just say two things about it.
//       There's a very good reason for it. And it can be turned off.
//
//       To turn it off, you need to edit the registry.
//       WARNING: Don't edit the registry unless you know what you are doing.
//       You could damage your operating system.
//
//       [a] Go to key:
//           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
//
//       [b] Create a dword value named MaximumTunnelEntries and set it to zero.
//
//       [c] Reboot.
//
//       Remember to put everything back the way it was when you're done.
//
//   - - Did it work?  Rerun the experiment above and note that the file
//       creation times are now different.
//       Now to continue with our experiment.
//       What will happen if we call REWRITE without first deleting the file?
//       Will it delete the existing file and create a new one?
//       Or will it overwrite the existing file?
//
//    9. Wait a few seconds.
//   10. Without first explicitly deleting the file,
//       call REWRITE with the same file name.
//   11. Determine the creation time of this new file. Call it C.
//
//   12. Compare B to C.  If they are the different, then the file must've
//       been deleted.  If they are the same, then the file was overwritten.
//
//   - - CONCLUSION:  The file creation times are the same. Calling rewrite
//       did not delete the existing file.  Rather it was overwritten.
//
//==============================================================================

{ 1. select a file name }
const
  gFileName : string = 'rewrite-test.txt';

procedure DeleteFileIfItExists;
begin
  if FileExists ( gFileName ) then
    if not SysUtils.DeleteFile ( gFileName ) then
      raise exception . create ( 'Cannot delete existing file.' );
end; // DeleteFileIfItExists

procedure CreateTheFile;
var
  aTextFile : textfile;
begin
  assignfile ( aTextFile, gFileName );
  rewrite ( aTextFile );
  try
    // To make the experiment more realistic, write something to the file.
    writeln ( aTextFile, 'Current time is: ', DateTimeToStr ( Now ) );
  finally
    closefile ( aTextFile );
  end;
end; // CreateTheFile

function DetermineFileCreationDate : tDateTime;
var
  aFileHandle   : tHandle;
  aCreationTime : tFileTime;
  aSystemTime   : tSystemTime;
begin
  aFileHandle := CreateFile ( pchar(gFileName),
                              GENERIC_READ,
                              FILE_SHARE_READ,
                              nil,
                              OPEN_EXISTING,
                              0,
                              0  );

  if aFileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    raise exception . create ( 'Cannot open file' );

  try

    GetFileTime ( aFileHandle,
                  @ aCreationTime,
                  nil,
                  nil  );

  finally
    CloseHandle ( aFileHandle );
  end;

  if not FileTimeToSystemTime ( aCreationTime, aSystemTime ) then
    raise exception . create ( 'Cannot convert file time' );

  Result := SysUtils . SystemTimeToDateTime ( aSystemTime );
end; // DetermineFileCreationDate

procedure WaitAFewSeconds;
begin
  sleep ( 5000 ); // 5 seconds should be enough
end;

procedure RunExperiment;
var
  A : tDateTime;
  B : tDateTime;
  C : tDateTime;
begin
  { 2.} DeleteFileIfItExists;
  { 3.} CreateTheFile;
  { 4.} A := DetermineFileCreationDate;
  { 5.} WaitAFewSeconds;
  { 6.} DeleteFileIfItExists;
  { 7.} CreateTheFile;
  { 8.} B := DetermineFileCreationDate;

  if A = B then
    raise exception . create ( 'The control file times are the same.'
                               + #13'Turn off file tunneling.'
                               + #13'See notes and warnings.' );

  { 9.} WaitAFewSeconds;
  {10.} CreateTheFile;
  {11.} C := DetermineFileCreationDate;

  writeln ( 'The original creation time was ', DateTimeToStr ( B ) );
  writeln ( 'The new      creation time is  ', DateTimeToStr ( C ) );

  if B = C then
    begin
      // This is the one
      writeln ( 'The file creation times are not the same.' );
      writeln ( 'REWRITE overwrites the existing file.' );
    end
  else
    begin
      // This is not run
      writeln ( 'The file creation times are the same.' );
      writeln ( 'REWRITE deletes and recreates the file.' );
    end;

end; // RunExperiment

begin
  try
    writeln ( 'The test will take about 10 seconds. Please wait.' );

    RunExperiment;

    // Give user a chance to see the answer
    writeln ( 'Press Enter to continue' );
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: It does not remove the directory link to the old file. It does however erase the old CONTENT.  The documentation is trying to tell you that the old file is truncated, and rewritten.  In the non-existant-file case, a new one is created.  Rewrite is complementary (opposite to) Append.

Comment: Agreed.  I would imagine that the documentation was correct at some point in the past (1984?) and it's never been worth anyone's time to test it or change it as the product has evolved.  Who would've thought that calling CreateFile with the CREATE_ALWAYS parameter does NOT always create a file?

Comment: Well, since `CreateFile` implementation is a secret known only to Microsofties, and since there is probably a reason that only Raymond Chen would know, as to why these things work the way they do, I'm not as surprised as I might have been.

Comment: The online documentation for the CREATE_ALWAYS parameter of CreateFile says "If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file".  I found that surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case i have noticed when working with Reset and Rewrite:

```
try
   ShowMessage('1');
   Reset(MyFile);
   ShowMessage('2');
except
      ShowMessage('3');
      Reset(MyFile);
      ShowMessage('4');
end;
```

Output that i had never ever think it could be possible: 1 3 4

Yes, yes, you are reading correctly, it is not a mistake: first call fails (the one in try part) and second one works (the one on except part).

Please note: Also happens the same with Rewrite.

That not allways happen, but if you let only one Reset or Rewrite, when taht would happen you will get an I/O error 103.

I had seen that if i re-do the Reset / Rewrite on a try...except...end if the first one fails the second one does not fail.

Of course, considering the fact that i am talking of cases where one single call  must not fail.

This happens (or at least is what i have seen) only on Windows 7 and 8/8.1 ... i had never see them to fail on WindowsXP.

You're advised... i think it is weird! Now i am replacing all calls to Reset / Rewrite so to include such double call (if first call fail re-try a second time).

And such trick works! At least for me! Such second call has never fail.

IMPORTANT: I am talking about cases where that first call must not fail... i am not considering any other cases.

Said in another way:

- There is no known reason why first call would fail, all is correct for it to not to fail at all... but sometimes it does not fail while others it does fail (on Win7/win8/Win8.1).

Tested on linear console code... run multiply times same code (same EXE), got different results.

As i said it is kind weird... solution is as i said: Redo Reset / Rewrite on a try except end.

Said in human words:

- If you can not (try) open the door (Reset/Rewrite call in try part), open the door (Reset/Rewrite on except part) and you will see you can (if first fails, second does not fail).

That of course if there is no known reason for first one to fail, except O.S. glitch !!! I can not call it in another form!

Comment: You must check for file I/O errors. `Reset - An error results if no existing external file of the given name exists or if the file cannot be opened with the current file mode.` An exception in Reset will close the file if it was open. I suggest to use {$I-} and handle file I/O errors correctly (Use IoResult).